# Regex on multiple terms

Tags: elasticsearch

First of all, I'm very new to ElasticSearch.

I've indexed 10m documents with the only string in ElasticSearch. This string contains terms/words, separated with space:

```
1:1 2 2 2 3 1:2 1:3
```

Every word is a code of an event, generated by some device. The string / document, itself, is a sequence of all events, generated by that device.

I need to find all documents/devices, that follow some patters/sequence of events. E.g.:

```
1:1 -> 1:2 -> 1:3
```

I do a regex search in ElasticSearch:

```
{
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: [
            {
                query_string: {
                    default_field: "device.event",
                    query: "1:1.*1:2"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine - returns 1 document.
However, when I do the query below, no matches are found:

```
{
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: [
            {
                query_string: {
                    default_field: "device.event",
                    query: "1:1.*1:3"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

With `.*` I want to skip all terms, between `1:1` and `1:3`, but, apparently, it doesn't work.